# Trouble implementing custom IntoIterator trait

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, bare-metal

I'm new to rust, so forgive me if the question is naive.

I'm trying to build an OS in rust and I'm following [this](https://tc.gts3.org/cs3210/2020/spring/lab/lab2.html) tutorial. The OS doesn't have memory management yet, so the goal is to build an object which is like a vector in that it can be pushed and popped etc, but it lives on the stack. We do this by initializing it with an array of fixed size. It looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StackVec<'a, T: 'a> {
    storage: &'a mut [T],
    len: usize
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> StackVec<'a, T> {

    pub fn new(storage: &'a mut [T]) -> StackVec<'a, T> {
        StackVec {
            storage: storage,
            len: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn with_len(storage: &'a mut [T], len: usize) -> StackVec<'a, T> {
        if len > storage.len(){
            panic!();
        }

        StackVec{
            storage: storage,
            len: len
        }
    }

    pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize {
        self.storage.len()
    }

    pub fn into_slice(self) -> &'a mut [T] {
        &mut self.storage[0..self.len]
    }
  
    // Other functions which aren't relevant for the question.

}
```

Popping and pushing increases and decreases the `len` variable and adds and removes entries from the appropriate place in the array.

Now, we also need to implement the IntoIterator trait. Given that the `StackVec` contains a reference to an array, I thought that I could just return an iterator from the underlying array:

```
impl <'a, T:'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = core::array::IntoIter; // <- Throws "not found in `core::array"

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.into_slice().into_iter()
    }
}
```

But no matter how much I play around with it, it still doesn't want to compile. I can't find a way to express using types that `into_iter`should return the iterator for the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have a borrowed slice, and you want to build an iterator returning owned `T` instances. You can't hand out what you don't own, so this isn't going to work.

Comment: Also note that `&'a mut [T]` is a slice, and not an array. An array is an owned data structure with a constant length, e.g. `[T; 5]`.

Comment: Your requirements aren't quite clear, but you most likely want something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5d94ba6191d27fe3efd47ef77ac5e59

Comment: Nitpick: you don't need the `T: 'a` it is inferred. Also, it looks like you reinvented [`array-vec`](https://lib.rs/crates/array-vec).

Comment: I'm curious: what Rust version are you running? (Try `cargo -V`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different problems here:

- You cannot use `array::IntoIterator` because you do not have an array, you have a slice, which is quite different. It can be solved, for example, by using the proper `core::slice::Iter` as in the example.
- You are trying to return `T` but in reality you only give access to `&T`, so return `Item` should be `&T`
- Your `into_slice` method uses a `&mut` which is not necessary, you can reslice the storage for this implementation.

```rust
impl <'a, T:'a> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = core::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.storage[0..self.len].into_iter()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3fd51610faef351ba018e86ad6f6a511)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, well true, let me switch the example then